# EF6 Code First Composite Primary AND Foreign Keys: Foreign Key must be mapped

Tags: foreign-keys, entity-framework-6, entity, ef-fluent-api, ef-model-builder

Well, after a morning of beating my head against the wall, I'm tossing this out there.

I have a DB Table (Table1) with a composite PK (Column1, Column2, Column3).  (Column1,Column3) is ALSO a FK to another table (Table2).

Trying to use Code First EF6 (6.1.3) and here's the models:

```
[Table("DB.Table1")]
public partial class Object1
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order=0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Column1 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    public byte Column2 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order=2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Column3 { get; set; }

    public virtual Object2 SecondObject { get; set; }
}

[Table("DB.Table2")]
public partial class Object2
{
    public Object2()
    {
        FirstObjects = new HashSet<Object1>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order=0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Column1 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Column3 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Object1> FirstObjects { get; set; }
}
```

My modelBuilder (Fluent API):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Object1>()
    .HasRequired(o => o.SecondObject)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(o => new { o.Column1, o.Column3 });
```

Maybe I'm missing something with the ICollection in Object2?

I'm getting an error that says "Foreign key constraint  from table Object1 (Column1, Column3) to table Object2 (Column1, Column3):: Insufficient mapping: Foreign key must be mapped to some AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign key association on the conceptual side."

I tried:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Object1>()
    .HasRequired(o => o.SecondObject)
    .WithMany(o => o.FirstObjects)
    .HasForeignKey(o => new { o.Column1, o.Column3 });
```

to no avail.  I got a "FirstObjects declared on Object2 has been configured with conflicting foreign keys" error.

This was CodeFirst generated from an existing database.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, your first fluent configutaion

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Object1>()
    .HasRequired(o => o.SecondObject)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(o => new { o.Column1, o.Column3 });
```

along with the `Object2.FirstObjects` navigation property creates **two** additional columns and **two** foreign keys which is incorrect and will cause problems.

The correct configuration for such model is the second one:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Object1>()
    .HasRequired(o => o.SecondObject)
    .WithMany(o => o.FirstObjects)
    .HasForeignKey(o => new { o.Column1, o.Column3 });
```

But make sure you start with fresh or no database because automatic migration cannot handle that change correctly. If you want to keep your database, then comment out any `Object1` or `Object2` configuration code and also the respective `DbSet`s. Then update the database. (make sure `Table1` and `Table2` get deleted). Then uncomment the `Object1` and `Object2` related code (with the second configuration!) and update the database. Now everything should be fine. I did it in a clean environment and it worked.

Comment: Ivan, appreciate the response.  When I tried that, I get a FirstObjects declared on Object2 has been configured with conflicting foreign keys" error.

Comment: Well, as I said, I've copy/pasted your code in my EF6.1.3 test db context and it just works. The only change I've made was to remove `DB.` from table names. SqlServer db btw, don't know what's your db. There is nothing more I can do, good luck.

Comment: Ivan, I found the problem with why the specified WithMany didn't work.  Object1 FK was set as (Column1,Column3) - Object2 FK was set (Column3,Column1).  Precedence matters :)  Thanks!

Comment: Sure it does! Glad that the problem is solved - beating the head against the wall is no good :)